# Knockout matrix

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, nested

I am trying to make a matrix matching table using knockout, but I'm stuck regarding the compare between the current data-bind and the parent data-bind.

Here is the [jsfiddle.net/wup9rxeu/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/wup9rxeu/4/)

```
<script type="text/html" id="cubeheader-template">
<th data-bind="text: $data.Name"></th>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="body-template">
<!-- ko foreach: $parent.modeldim -->
<td>x</td>
<!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

What I want to accomplished is that when the table is populated with x and - for each td, based on the modelcubdim data.

I need some pointer on comparing the ID against the parent ID and if it's a match, then X or else -

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest performing the comparison in a viewmodel and use the view just to display those results.

Comment: `f_martinez` answer (brilliant) does your work before load well check this using binding Handlers a different approach http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/X82aC/1246/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand your model with transformed data to represent every cell in the table.

```
// just for easy searching items by its ID
data.itemById = function(arr, id){
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(arr, function(item){
        return item.ID == id;
    });
};

// the property that will hold actual data for *every* table row
// in the format { Name: [Cub Name], Data [array of "x" and "-"] }
data.series = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.modelcub, function(cub){
    var cubdim = data.itemById(data.modelcubdim, cub.ID);
    return {
        Name: cub.Name,
        Data: ko.utils.arrayMap(data.modeldim, function(dim){
            var item = cubdim && data.itemById(cubdim.CubeDimension, dim.ID);
            return item ? "x" : "-";
        })
    };
});
```

Then slightly change your markup:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: series">            
<tr> 
    <th data-bind="text: Name"></th>  
    <!-- ko foreach: Data -->
    <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And you will get it working like here: http://jsfiddle.net/wup9rxeu/5/